# AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While creating an EC2 instance on AWS, using .boto (python), how to set the Availability zone in  given region. I am able to pass region as paramater. How and where pass zone eg : Region = us-west-1, zone = us-west-1b, us-west-1c ??? Suppose I want ec2 instance in Region us-west-1 and zone = us-west-1c, because my 1 TB EBS volume is there in us-west-1, us-west-1c !!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `boto`, a region is required to connect to the Amazon EC2 service. This is because each region operates independently and boto will send the request to the indicated region. This is merely to tell boto where to send the API request.

When using boto to launch an Amazon EC2 instance using the [`run_instances()`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html) command, the Availability Zone is indicated either via:

- `placement`: Used with EC2-Classic, or
- `subnet`: Used with EC2-VPC

These days, it is most likely that you are using Amazon VPC (Virtual Private Cloud), which launches instances into a secure network. VPCs contain subnets and each subnet is allocated to a specific Availability Zone:

[image: Amazon VPC subnets]

(from [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html))

Therefore, when launching an instance you specify a `subnet`. This subnet is associated with an Availability Zone, so the instance is launched in that subnet and that Availability Zone. The Availability Zone is not specified directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
  aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>',
  aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')
```

or

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
```

Don't pass `a`, `b`, `c` etc in region code. Eg. `us-west-1b` wont work, `us-west-1` will.